# Consuming WCF Service (Certificate Authentication) by ASP.NET 2.0 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have created an WCF Service with Certificate authentication and it works perfectly with WCF Client. But the issue is when I want to consume the same WCF Service by WebService client (May be the client might have only .net 2.0 framework).

WCF Service method which I am trying to call is

```
public class Service : IService
 {
    public string GetWelcomeMessage()
    {
        return "Consuming WCF Service as Webservice";
    }
 }
```

My snippet of WCF Service config is as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndPoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndPointBinding">
                <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndPointBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=tempServerCert"/>
        <!--<clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>-->
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have added the WCF Service as "Add Web Referance" in ASP.Net 2.0 application created on VS2005 and my Client's (ASP.net 2.0 application) web.config is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndPoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndPointBinding">
                <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndPointBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=tempServerCert"/>
        <!--<clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>-->
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting SoapHandlerException while making call to the WCF Service. Exception details are as below

```
Message:        An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

InnerException: null

Stack Trace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at w15mtc15j128.Service.GetWelcomeMessage() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\wcfwebserviceclient\99c8cdb0\4f5c6355\App_WebReferences.e4pgkrzt.0.cs:line 151
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WCFWebServiceClient\Default.aspx.cs:line 17
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232500/how-to-configure-security-when-calling-wcf-service-from-net-2-0-client

Comment: I have followed the same procedure of using basicHttpBinding with Certificate security but still I am facing the SoapHeaderException error message.